# I created this loop but I want to assign it a range(3) so it does not print a abundance of numbers... any ideas?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
items = ["pants","shirt","belt","socks"]
prices = ["26","35","100","8"]
cart = []
for item in items:
   cart += items
   for price in prices:
    cart += prices
    print(cart)
```

this will print(item,price)

```
checkout = range(5)
for check in checkout:
   checkout += cart
```

I want it to only print 5 times

Comment: You should not use a nested loop. You need either two loops or a loop through the two parallel lists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting 3 and 5 since you have 4 items/prices, but I think you want the `zip` function to combine the two lists:

```
>>> items = ["pants","shirt","belt","socks"]
>>> prices = ["26","35","100","8"]
>>> for z in zip(items, prices):
...     print(z)
...
('pants', '26')
('shirt', '35')
('belt', '100')
('socks', '8')
```

Comment: ahhh your 100% right i forgot about that the zip function